# ObjectAt(0) doesn't work with Ember.Controller

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I'm trying to upgrade my Ember application to the latest Ember 1.13.2 and therefore am trying to replace all `Ember.ArrayController` with `Ember.Controller`.

I've got a problem with the category-controller of my blog. The data retrieved from my server looks like this:

```
 "posts": [
    {
      "category": {
         "id": "1",
         "name": "tech"}
      "title": "my title",
      "body": "post-content",
      "isPublished": true,
    },
   ...
   ]
```

In my category-controller I need both, the category-id and the category-name.

With the `Ember.ArrayController` I used `objectAt(0)` to get both from the first post loaded in the model for that purpose but this doesn't work with `Ember.Controller` anymore.

**How can I get these two attributes in my controller?**

This code doesn't work anymore:

```
  breadCrumb: function(){
    return this.objectAt(0).get('category').get('name');
  }.property('model.[]'),

  categoryId: function(){
    return this.objectAt(0).get('category').get('id');
  }.property('model.[]'),
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just get it from the model directly instead of using the proxy behavior:

```
return this.get('model').objectAt(0).get('category').get('name');
```

Or, if you like shorthand:

```
return this.get('model.firstObject.category.name');
```

EDIT: While I'm at it, you could also declare these as aliases:

```
breadCrumb: Ember.computed.alias('model.firstObject.category.name'),
```

If you don't do that, you should probably change your dependent key. Your property won't update if the nested properties change. You need to use something like `model.firstObject.category.name` or `model.@each.category.name`.

Comment: As usual a great post. Thanks a lot for the explanation.